# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.circuit.library'

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience

I am importing `from qiskit.circuit.library import MCMTVChain` on python IDLE editor but it showing error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.circuit.library'` although it's working fine on `google colab`. Also why Qiskit does not work properly on python IDLE it's show lots of other error not just this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably haven't installed the qiskit module. Qiskit can be installed via :

```
pip install qiskit
```

Try the following commands in command prompt, one of them should work (if your PATH variables are appropriately set):

```
py -m pip install qiskit
```

Or

```
python -m pip install qiskit
```

Or if you have more than one python versions, you can try:

```
py -'version number like 3.7' pip install qiskit
```

without the quotes.

This should install the qiskit module and then you can import it.